# Количество обращений к методам класса C++

Tags: c++

Имеется класс, содержащий большое количество методов:

```
class TChild : public TParent
{

public:

  void foo();
  void bar();
  ....
  void xyz();

};
```

Возможно ли вести подсчёт количества вызовов `public` методов этого класса?

Например:

```
class TChild : public TParent

{

public:

  static int MethodsExecCount;

  void foo();
  void bar();
  ....
  void xyz();

};

.................................

TChild::foo() {

  this->bar();

}

TChild::xyz() {

  int a = 1+1;

}

TChild::bar() {

  this->MethodsExecCount;

}

...............................

int main() {

   TChild ch;

   ch->foo();
   printf(%d,ch->MethodsExecCount); //вернёт 2, т.к. вызывались foo() и bar()  
   ch->xyz();
   printf(%d,ch->MethodsExecCount); //вернёт 3

}
```

Как можно реализовать подсчёт вызовов методов внутри класса?

Comment: Добавить в каждом вызове инкремент счетчика (а уж класса или объекта - решать вам).

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что интересует общее решение, позволяющее забывать о нём при добавлении новых публичных методов? Из коробки в cpp нет таких абстракций, но можно придумать, скажем, хитрый указатель, который будет считать вызовы.

Comment: Для чего Вам это нужно?

Comment: Да, интересует именно общее решение. Методов может быть разное количество. Нужно это, как ни странно, для того, чтобы считать вызовы в конкретном классе. Пока пытаюсь сделать обвязку с помощью Template, но вдруг есть более элегантное решение данной задачи.

Comment: Если для тестов может [gcov](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gcov&ved=2ahUKEwirpeuJzbncAhUFjSwKHWwCCv0QFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw2BBLGSco6-VYEpoy-TsIIk)?

Comment: Вам зачем нужно знать количество вызовов? Если это нужно одноразово (редко), то это можно сделать с помощью IDE. Встроенных средств языка для этого нет.

Comment: Если кратко, то мне нужно знать количество вызовов для определения активности пользователя при работе с этим классом. Если в течение определенного времени количество вызовов не изменилось, то пользователь считается неактивным (неактивным именно в контексте моей задачи)

Comment: Раз Вам нужно собирать метрики во время исполнения не для целей тестирования, то Вам нужно внедрять сбор метрик в класс. Простейший метод описан в первом же комментарии. Никаких автоматических и более простых средств не существует.

Comment: Общего решения не может быть. Класс  не может знать как  будет меняться состояние своих экземпляров или  их поведение, пока не будет иметь контроль над каждым действием.   Об этом может знать только клиент класса. Это актуально и в реальной жизни...

Comment: Есть отладчики\профилировщики, которые позволяют считать вызовы функций, вроде callgrind из valgrind так умеет, еще есть годный профайлер - orbit